# li list moving out of place as transition font size changes

Tags: html, css

I've made a series of six boxes which when the user hovers over the fonts-size inside is increased, however this moves the boxes as you can see in my example. How do I fix this?

Also the border size is 2px, but where two boxes meet it appears to be 4px, how would I get the two touching sides to overlap (preferably without negative margins as this would get confusing once the screen is resized).

Thanks for any help in advance.

https://jsfiddle.net/frw95vdL/

```
#main-content a {
color: #000;
border: #000 solid 2px;
display: table-cell;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
text-decoration: none;
-webkit-transition: font-size ease 3s, background-color ease 0.7s;
-moz-transition: font-size ease 3s, background-color ease 0.7s;
-o-transition: font-size ease 3s, background-color ease 0.7s;
transition: font-size ease 3s, background-color ease 0.7s;
}
```

Comment: Give `margin: -1px;` to the `#main-content li` element to fix the border issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`font-size` cause of this and I recommend you a solution that use `transform: scale()` instead of `font-size`. Actually I think `font-size` is a bad idea for do this and transform scale will better. I made some change to your fiddle.

```
#main-content a:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
    transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/frw95vdL/1/)**

Comment: Here is the above fiddle with the margin fix added: https://jsfiddle.net/0t7josk5/

Comment: @Carlton yes it works too, but I'm sure `margin` or `padding` with `negative value` are invalid and wrong way to fix problems! it's little hacky but I don't prefer to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, seeing as the margin is only -1 I'm sure not too much could go wrong? :)